# R - subscript out of bounds & $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors?

Tags: json, r, weather-api

I want to get a list daily weather data of different dates from weather underground - `meanwindspdi, meanwdird and humidity`.

For instance:

```
date.range <- c("2016-01-29", "2016-01-30", "2016-02-29")
```

And the URL for a date - 2016-01-29 :

```
http://api.wunderground.com/api/API_KEY/history_20160129/q/EGLL.json
```

Sample data/ json:

```
{
  ...
        "dailysummary": [
        { "date": {
        "pretty": "12:00 AM GMT on January 29, 2016",
        "year": "2016",
        "mon": "01",
        "mday": "29",
        "hour": "00",
        "min": "00",
        "tzname": "Europe/London"
        },
        "fog":"0","rain":"1","snow":"0","snowfallm":"", "snowfalli":"","monthtodatesnowfallm":"", "monthtodatesnowfalli":"","since1julsnowfallm":"", "since1julsnowfalli":"","snowdepthm":"", "snowdepthi":"","hail":"0","thunder":"0","tornado":"0","meantempm":"10", "meantempi":"50","meandewptm":"8", "meandewpti":"47","meanpressurem":"1016.97", "meanpressurei":"30.03","meanwindspdm":"32", "meanwindspdi":"20","meanwdire":"SW","meanwdird":"230","meanvism":"12.0", "meanvisi":"7.5","humidity":"82","maxtempm":"12", "maxtempi":"54","mintempm":"7", "mintempi":"45","maxhumidity":"95","minhumidity":"67","maxdewptm":"10", "maxdewpti":"51","mindewptm":"7", "mindewpti":"45","maxpressurem":"1022", "maxpressurei":"30.18","minpressurem":"1011", "minpressurei":"29.86","maxwspdm":"46", "maxwspdi":"29","minwspdm":"26", "minwspdi":"16","maxvism":"30.0", "maxvisi":"19.0","minvism":"4.6", "minvisi":"3.0","gdegreedays":"0","heatingdegreedays":"16","coolingdegreedays":"0","precipm":"0.6", "precipi":"0.02","precipsource":"Precip6GroupSynop","heatingdegreedaysnormal":"","monthtodateheatingdegreedays":"","monthtodateheatingdegreedaysnormal":"","since1sepheatingdegreedays":"","since1sepheatingdegreedaysnormal":"","since1julheatingdegreedays":"","since1julheatingdegreedaysnormal":"","coolingdegreedaysnormal":"","monthtodatecoolingdegreedays":"","monthtodatecoolingdegreedaysnormal":"","since1sepcoolingdegreedays":"","since1sepcoolingdegreedaysnormal":"","since1jancoolingdegreedays":"","since1jancoolingdegreedaysnormal":"" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Loop the date.range with the code below:

```
dailysummary <- fromJSON('http://api.wunderground.com/api/API_KEY/history_20160129/q/EGLL.json')[["history"]][["dailysummary"]]

library(plyr)
hdwd <- data.frame()
hdwd <- rbind(hdwd, ldply(dailysummary,
          function(x) c(x$meanwindspdi, x$meanwdird, x$humidity)
        ))
```

Error:

```
Error in x$meanwindspdi : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

So I changed it to:

```
function(x) c(x$meanwindspdi, x$meanwdird, x$humidity)
```

Error:

```
 Error in x[["meanwindspdi"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

What I want to get is similar to this [guide](http://allthingsr.blogspot.my/2012/04/getting-historical-weather-data-in-r.html) (it has the same error too):

```
Airport Date    Fog Rain    Snow    AvgTemp AvgVisibility   MaxTemp MinTemp
SFO 13149   0   1   0   55  14  62  47
SFO 13150   0   1   0   53  11  55  50
SFO 13151   0   1   0   51  14  56  46
SFO 13152   0   0   0   56  16  62  50
SFO 13153   0   0   0   54  14  60  48
SFO 13154   0   1   0   52  14  59  45
SFO 13155   0   1   0   56  14  61  50
SFO 13156   0   0   0   51  16  57  45
SFO 13157   0   0   0   49  16  56  41
SFO 13158   0   0   0   54  10  61  46
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `ldply` expects a list, hence the l, `ldply(list(dailysummary), ...`

Comment: @rawr thanks for the help!

Comment: I think in your question it should read "So I changed it to: function(x) c(x[, "meanwindspdi"], x[, "meanwdird"], x[, "humidity"])"  - currently you state the same function again.